# What would cause requestAnimationFrame to return undefined instead of an id?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Sometimes when I use requestAnimationFrame, I store the id it returns as documented here under the "Return value" section:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

This id can be used with cancelRequestAnimationFrame:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame

However, there are random times when requestAnimationFrame returns undefined and when it does, it does it repeatedly, not just on the last call. This doesn't seem to be documented in the above links. There's a github project that experienced the same thing here:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threejs-inspector/issues/21

and there's a commit there to fix it but I can't see what might have caused it. The sequence I have seen happen is the id increments on each successive call but then is undefined for every call afterwards.

The code I experience this with is:

```
animateProgress = function(t) {
    var n = t - this._previousTimeStamp;
    this._previousTimeStamp = t;
    this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
        return animateProgress(time)
    });
    console.log("id is ", this.requestId);
}
animateProgress(0);
```

This is used during a loading sequence and there are some warnings in the console like:

[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 3644ms

My loading sequence has a couple of requestAnimationFrame calls and some seem to be getting delayed. Maybe they are interfering with each other?

Comment: Can you post the code that you're having this problem with? You may be overwriting the variable on accident somewhere in between the first call and all subsequent ones thereafter

Comment: I have updated the original post with some code. The code where the id is undefined is quite basic and works fine on its own but it's part of a loading sequence where there's another requestAnimationFrame call, which sometimes gets delayed. I'm not sure if that's affecting it.

Comment: Store the request ID in a local variable, log it to the console, before writing it to `this.requestId`.  Are the results the same?

Comment: Yes, the results are the same. The reference this.requestId isn't being overwritten or being accessed in the cancel call through the wrong scope, the function call requestAnimationFrame is returning undefined instead of an id.

Comment: [Can't repro.](https://jsfiddle.net/rv2ya5ns/) For the case you linked to, they were overriding the original `requestAnimationFrame` method. Are you doing something like that too? What does `console.log(requestAnimationFrame.toString())` outputs?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that, that seems to be the problem. When I log requestAnimationFrame.toString(), it changes when the id is undefined. I'll have a look to see where that code is located and how it's redefining requestAnimationFrame. How do I mark that comment as the solution?

Comment: It turned out to be the same issue I linked to in the original post. I was using that repo (it's a Chrome extension) and that pull request wasn't merged. I didn't pick up on the fact that code was redefining requestAnimationFrame. I was trying to find the problem in my own code, not realising it was the browser extension because the error was raised in my code. Thanks again for pointing this out, I would have wasted so much time looking in the wrong place for this.